# sass add a class to the top of the scope

Tags: css, sass

```
#mydiv{
    //csscode....
    ul{
    //csscode....
         li{
         //csscode....
            a{
            //csscode....
                &:hover{
                    //csscode....

                    (HOW TO ADD a CLASS OUTSIDE #mydiv)
                }
            }
         }
    }

}
```

I want to add a class for ie8 only. 
looks like

```
.it-ie8 #mydiv ul li a:hover{}
```

Should I just write like above or I could add something inside

```
&:hover{
 (HOW TO ADD a CLASS OUTSIDE #mydiv)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can, Using an ampersand symbol after an identifier nested, will re-create the tree from the point, starting with the identifier first.

IE:

**SCSS:**

```
#mydiv{
    //csscode....
    ul{
    //csscode....
         li{
         //csscode....
            a{
            //csscode....
                &:hover{
                    //csscode....
                    .it-ie8 & {color:red;}
                }
            }
         }
    }

}
```

**Will Compile to:**

**CSS**

```
.it-ie8 #mydiv ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```